# File uploaded to ftp server is corrupted c#

Tags: c#

I'm not sure why my file is corrupted. I'm not using StreamReader which has been a common problem that most have had. It uploads successfully I just can't seem to find the issue on why the file is corrupted even after searching through the various solved stack overflow questions.

```
    public ActionResult UploadFtpFile(HttpPostedFileBase promoImgFile)
    {
        bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
        string fileName = null;
        string completeDPath = "xxxxx";
        string username = "xxxx";
        string password = "xxxxx";
        FtpWebRequest ftpClient;
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;
        List<string> directories = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            foreach (string fileItemName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileItemName];
                fileName = file.FileName;
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    //Create FtpWebRequest object
                    ftpClient = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + completeDPath + "/" + fileName));
                    //Set request method
                    ftpClient.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                    //Set Credentials
                    ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

                    //Opens a file to read
                    Stream objFile = file.InputStream;

                    //By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed after a command is executed.
                    ftpClient.KeepAlive = true;

                    //Set the data transfer type
                    ftpClient.UseBinary = true;

                    //Set content length
                    ftpClient.ContentLength = file.ContentLength;

                    //Get Stream of the file
                    Stream objStream = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[objFile.Length];
                    //Write file content
                    objStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    objStream.Close();
                    objFile.Close();

                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            isSavedSuccessfully = false;
        }

        //return Json(new { promoImgFile = directories });
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { promoImgFile = directories });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's this line right here:

```
   Stream objFile = file.InputStream;
```

Years of learning, I figured out one thing that works:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
```

Then work off the MemoryStream.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is still corrupted once uploaded to server. Do you think the issue could be how the file content is being written?

Comment: Can you try writing the file/image to the IIS server first? See if it is corrupted there. If it isn't then you know its something to do with the FTP connection.

Comment: it's still corrupted for some reason, I honestly have no idea what it could be

Comment: I am pretty sure (HttpPostedFileBase promoImgFile) should be an array like (HttpPostedFileBase[] uploadedFiles) and you can do a foreach on the array to get the individual file. Try that to the IIS server and see if they are corrupt. If they are still corrupted then post your code to the <Form>.

Answer (score 1):

### Example (for text)

Docs: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx)

The important part for your issue:

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

### Example (for an image)

```
byte [] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(imageSource);
request.ContentLength = imageData.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

Comment: Well since I'm uploading an image I know that I can't use StreamReader, what would I use instead of that class?